# Getting curl through a proxy

Tags: curl, proxy

Using curl to explore an API which consists of a reverse proxy and two uses of htttps protocol.
The following is one attempt which I have questions about

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>curl -k --digest -u admin -x https://192.168.102.102:443 -L https://192.168.102.102:4242/quarters/reports -v  
Enter host password for user 'admin':  
*   Trying 192.168.102.102...  
* Connected to 192.168.102.102 (192.168.102.102) port 443 (#0)  
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to 192.168.102.102:4242  
* Server auth using Digest with user 'admin'  
> CONNECT 192.168.102.102:4242 HTTP/1.1  
> Host: 192.168.102.102:4242  
> User-Agent: curl/7.46.0  
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
* Proxy CONNECT aborted  
* Connection #0 to host 192.168.102.102 left intact  
curl: (56) Proxy CONNECT aborted
```

This works in FireFox in that if I enter the url
https://192.168.102.102/quarters/reports
I get back all reports in json format.

As to my questions:
1. Does the output in the first section seem as expected?
    Connecting to the proxy server then tunneling to the app server?
2. What is the likely reason for the connection to abort?
3. It says that the #0 connection is left intact, connection to proxy?
4. Is the authentication being applied to both urls or only one?
5. How do I get is to go all the way and return the resource?

UPDATE:
Have tried the above with no authentication, basic and digest with the same results.

UPDATE 2:
If the command is changed to:
`curl -k --digest -u admin https://192.168.102.102:443 -L https://192.168.102.102:4242/quarters/reports -v`
I get:

```
Enter host password for user 'admin':
* Rebuilt URL to: https://192.168.102.102:443/
*   Trying 192.168.102.102...
* Connected to 192.168.102.102 (192.168.102.102) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
Deleted to save space
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
Deleted to save space
* SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
* Server auth using Digest with user 'admin'
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.102.102
> User-Agent: curl/7.46.0
> Accept: */*
```

Followed by a 200 response with the login page in the body
Then 301 and 401 and 401

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I am on the 192.168.102.102 machine and enter:
  curl -k --digest -u admin:password https://192.168.102.102:443 -L 
  https://192.168.102.102/quarters/reports/ -trace-ascii
  I get the html of the home page/login page and the json response.
  If I am on the Windows 10 client and enter the same command at the command 
  prompt without "-L" the final part of the return is:
  "[See Other](/login/?_dc=2017-11-21%2010:08:40.144615793%20-0500%20%0A%20%20EST&redirect=/quarters/reports).
  With the "-L" get a 401 status.
  This is then a partial answer not sure why it works on server but not on 
  client

UPDATE the syntax "curl -k --digest -u admin:password -L https://192.168.102.102/quarters/reports gives me the json response only

Answer (score 0):

Once I corrected the curl install on Windows 10 it gave the same response as curl on Linux. This is then a final answer.